# Format typescript file the same as C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I would like to format my [`typescript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) files the same as my [`C#`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/csharp) code files.

I am able to get [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/) to format the open brace on a new line, but I am unable to get Visual Studio to format my parameters the same as `C#`

Here is an example of my `C#` class

[image]

I would like my typescript file to have the same formatting where my parameters line up.

Here is an example of my `typescript` class incorrectly formatted:

[image]

Here is an example of how I would like my `typescript` file to be formatted:

[image]

I have checked the Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript section but I am unable to find the correct setting to align my parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't about Visual Studio but you could use `tslint`. `tslint` is a linter for Typescript. It supports many many rules and preferences. I'm not sure if there is a plugin for Visual Studio that supports `tslint` (I know there is one for Visual Studio Code thou).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this more easily with [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) files.

By using this you can also share it across your team so everyone can have a consistent formatting rules.

Comment: does visual studio 2015 support this by default or would I have to use a plugin?

Comment: No, it doesn't but there is a plugin available on the editorconfig site. You should be able to find it on the plugins section.

Comment: As far as I know `.editorconfig` is (currently) pretty limited because of its few options. But I like it as well :)